# How to execute a function in the MainLayout(widget) on_dismiss event of Popup in python kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Python kivy 2.1.0

In the code a popup opens when you press the button **set credentials**
[Main layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkkis.png)

In the popup I want the user to type details and when they press **set credentials** I want to **dismiss** the popup and execute a funcction inside the **on_release** event of the popup or maybe pass those details to mainLayout somehow. The problem is I think kivy doesn't relate the popup box to the mainLayout. But I need those details in the mainLayout so that so that I can use them there (pressing button or showing the details in the log may be)
[pop layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEIqP.png)

Here's my .py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

#set screen ratio
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (480/1.8, 800/1.8)

Builder.load_file('ui.kv')


class FaucetLayout(Widget):
    def set_cred(self, cred):
        print(cred)
        pass

class DollarApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return FaucetLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DollarApp().run()
```

Heres my .kv file:

```
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory


<CredPopup@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: False 
    title: "Type your Credentials"
    size_hint: 1, .5
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'top': .95}
    on_dismiss: root.set_cred({'username':username.text, 'password':password.text})
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        padding: 10
        spacing: 15
        size: self.width, self.height

        TextInput:
            hint_text: "type your username"
            hint_text_color: 0, 0, 0, .5
            id: username
            multiline: False
            size_hint: 1, .1
            focus: True

        TextInput:
            hint_text: "type your password" 
            hint_text_color: 0, 0, 0, .5
            id: password
            multiline: False
            size_hint: 1, .1
        Button:
            text: "Set Credentials"
            size_hint: .4, .1
            on_press: root.dismiss()

        




<FaucetLayout>
    GridLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        cols: 1
        spacing: 10
        Label:
            id: faucet_log
            text: '[color=000]log will appear here[/color]'
            markup: True
            background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            size_hint: .5, None
            height: root.height/2
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: self.background_color
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size: root.width, self.height
            padding: 30
            spacing: 25

            Button:
                text: 'Set Credentials'
                size_hint: .6, None
                height: 40
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
                on_release: Factory.CredPopup().open()

            Button:
                text: 'Start'
                size_hint: .6, None
                height: 40
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y':.9 }
```

Getting this error:

> File "t:\Codes\Kivy\dollar\ui.kv", line 9, in 
> on_dismiss: root.set_cred({'username':username.text, 'password':password.text})    File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in
> kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.**getattr**  AttributeError: 'CredPopup'
> object has no attribute 'set_cred'

So sorry if I couldn't express myself.  I am new to asking questions here. I'm not a pro python programmer, just try to solve some daily personal task with python by following tutorials on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Got answer from discord.

> root refers to the base of the rule it is in, you could use app.root in this case instead to use to refer to the app's root widget .

```
<CredPopup@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: False 
    title: "Type your Credentials"
    size_hint: 1, .5
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'top': .95}
    on_dismiss: app.root.set_cred({'username':username.text, 'password':password.text})
```